# Connecting Django to URL

Tags: django, url

So I have a domain, lets call it patrick.net. I also have a remote server at some IP address, let's say 123.435.789.000. Developing a Django framework and have all of the URLs set up. How do I make the transition from http://localhost:8000/profile to http://patrick.net/profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're hosting the application on your own server, you should review the Django docs on deployment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/  There's a lot of variables in terms of what your system setup will look like, so there's no easy answer.

If your needs are less complex, I'd recommend a more managed solution like [Webfaction](http://www.webfaction.com/hosting/django-hosting) or [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com)

Comment: You could mention that DNS is what makes the name patrick.net point to the IP address 123.456.789.000. Or some other address with legal octets :-)